# Running Rails app with JRuby shows "LoadError"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

My rails app runs well with Ruby 1.8.7. Now I want to test my rails app with JRuby. But JRuby tells me it cannot autoload certain files, but these files exist correctly in the path.

```
LoadError (Expected E:/youwenti/app/models/article/reference_aspect.rb to define
 Article::ReferenceAspect):
  app/models/article.rb:6:in `Article'
  app/models/article.rb:3:in `(root)'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1058:in `load'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2080:in `send'
  app/models/article.rb:99:in `latest'
  app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:36:in `show'
  app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:21:in `index'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2076:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2076:in `send'
  compass (0.11.7) lib/compass/app_integration/rails/actionpack2/action_controll
er.rb:7:in `process_with_compass'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  sass (3.1.15) rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
```

I already have `Article::ReferenceAspect` defined in `E:/youwenti/app/models/article/reference_aspect.rb`. How to solve the problem?

Rails version is 2.3.14

JRuby version is

```
jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-02-22 3e82bc8) (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.7.0_02) [Windows XP-x86-java]
```